# How to deploy flex application to tablets or mobile phones with Flash Builder?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

In [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/flex/flex_deploy_application.htm) they are talking about deploying flex application to a tomcat webserver with Flash Builder. But I want to deploy to a tablet or mobile phone. How to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, they no longer make Flash runtimes for mobile platforms.  The best you can do is make an Adobe Air app.